# How can I automatically mount an NTFS partition in Lubuntu on startup?

Tags: mount, ntfs

I run windows on a NTFS partition and Lubuntu 11.10 on the other. I want to access the Thunderbird Profiles on the NTFS Partition when I'm using Lubuntu.

But I can't mount the NTFS from the beginning with fstab (tried some manual editing and default parameters using mount-manager) as every time I rebooted, an error occurred (at the Lubuntu loading screen I had to press a key for ignoring the mounting and continue booting).

When I start the system without mounting via fstab, I get READ-access in the file manager. The HDD is obviously mounted as soon as I've clicked on it in my places. It's a 120 GB SSD by the way with Windows XP installed.

So what could I do to still auto-mount my NTFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `ntfs-3g` if it is not already installed. Then edit fstab, I copied mine below: (change the first and maybe the second column)

```
UUID=3E9891A29891596B /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
```

Answer (score 3):

Two links to help you:

1. A GUI Tool: http://maketecheasier.com/easily-automount-windows-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu/2012/04/06
2. Guide to modify fstab: http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/05/how-to-mount-a-windows-partition-on-linux-automatically-on-each-start-up/

Comment: The gui tool (ntfs-config) is working perfectly on lubuntu. Very easy to use :)